# Does the dimension of the row space equal dimension of the column space for complex matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

In the case of real matrices, the dimension of the row space equals the dimension of the column space:  $\text{dim } \text{span}(A) = \text{dim }\text{span}(A^T)$. But for complex matrices the transpose gets replaced by the conjugate transpose so $$\text{dim } \text{span}(A) = \text{dim }\text{span}(A^H).$$

Nonetheless, I'm wondering if for complex matrices it is also true that $\text{dim } \text{span}(A) = \text{dim }\text{span}(A^T)$. I.e., if we use the regular transpose instead of the conjugate transpose do we still have equality?

For this to be true, it would also have to be that $\text{dim }\text{span}(A) = \text{dim }\text{span}(\bar{A})$. In other words, that the elementwise complex conjugate operation preserves rank. Is this true?

Thanks.

Comment: It is not difficult to prove that if $\{v_1, \cdots, v_k\}$ is a basis of $\text{span}(A)$, then $\{\overline{v_1},\cdots, \overline{v_k}\}$ is a basis of $\text{span}(\overline{A})$.

Comment: Thanks. Obviously the dimension of the span of $\{ \bar{v_1}, \ldots, \bar{v_k} \}$ can't be greater than $k$, but I guess I'm wondering if it can be less thank $k$, which is what I should try to prove.

Comment: As @DongRyulKim wrote, if $v_k$ form a basis of $\text{span}(A)$, then $\overline{v_k}$ form a basis of $\text{span}(\overline{A})$, so the dimensions of both spaces must be $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the proof of $\dim \text{span}(A)=\dim \text{span} (\overline{A})$, we first consider of basis $\{{v_1}, \cdots, {v_k}\}$ of $\text{span}(A)$. Since $\text{span}(A) = \text{span}(v_1, \cdots, v_k)$, we have $\text{span}(\overline{A}) = \text{span}(\overline{v_1}, \cdots, \overline{v_k})$. If there exist complex numbers $c_1, \cdots, c_k$ such that $c_1 \overline{v_1} + \cdots + c_k \overline{v_k} = 0$, then we can consider the conjugate of each side to obtain $\overline{c_1} v_1 + \cdots + \overline{c_k} v_k = 0$. Becuase $v_1, \cdots, v_k$ is linearly independent in $\mathbb{C}$, we have $c_1 =\cdots = c_k = 0$. Hence $\overline{v_1}, \cdots , \overline{v_k}$ is also linearly independent. Thus $\{\overline{v_1}, \cdots, \overline{v_k} \}$ is a basis and the dimension of $\text{span}(A)$ is also $k$.

Actually the proof of $\dim \text{span}(A) =\dim \text{span}(A^T)$ for real numbers will also work in the same way for complex numbers. (because it only uses the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is a field)